# Module Pandas has no attribute Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am suddenly getting this strange error. No such issue till some time back at all. Using Spyder 5.0 and Pandas 1.2.4.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe()
```

Error log:

```
runfile('D:/STUDY/DATA SCIENCE/Data Science with Python/PROJECT - NYC 311/untitled0.py', wdir='D:/STUDY/DATA SCIENCE/Data Science with Python/PROJECT - NYC 311')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\STUDY\DATA SCIENCE\Data Science with Python\PROJECT - NYC 311\untitled0.py", line 2, in <module>
    df=pd.Dataframe()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 244, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'
```

Comment: it's `DataFrame()` not `Dataframe()`

Answer (score 0):

`Dataframe` should be `DataFrame`. Notice the upper case `F` in `Frame`.

Comment: @AnuragDabas I think this exactly answers the OP's question.

Comment: *I think this should be a comment instead of an answer...And yes this exactly answers the OP's question...but anyway...As you wish **:)**